# How do you make react-tsparticles scrollable in a website? When I scroll down, I want it to go up and not sticky

Tags: reactjs, web

I am using react-tsparticles in my react website to make it cool. I want the particles to be scrollable and not sticky.
What styling do you add to make it go up when I scroll down?

Below is the code I'm using...

```
<Particles
  options={{
    background: {
      
    },
    fpsLimit: 60,
    interactivity: {
      events: {
        resize: true,
      }
    },
    particles: {
      color: {
        value: "#ffffff",
      },
      number: {
        density: {
          enable: true,
          area: 800,
        },
        value: 80,
      },
      opacity: {
        value: 0.5,
      },
      shape: {
        type: "circle",
      },
      size: {
        random: true,
        value: 2,
      },
    },
    detectRetina: true,
  }}

  
  
  style={{
    marginTop: '10vh',
    height:'89vh',
    paddingTop: "2px",
    }}

/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the [`fullScreen`](https://particles.js.org/docs/interfaces/Options_Interfaces_IOptions.IOptions.html) option to `false`.

```
<Particles
  options={{
    fullScreen: false,
    background: {
      
    },
    ...
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. What if you want to increase the size of the canvas? Like width and height of the canvas?

Comment: @MohamedAhmed The `Particles` component accepts `width` and `height` props. See https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles/blob/main/components/react/README.md#props. Or you can do it through the `style` prop like your original code.